# Zariski cohomology of an etale sheaf vs etale cohomology.

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{F}_{Zar}$ be a Zariski sheaf (on the big site of schemes or $S$-schemes) and $\mathcal{F}_{et}$ be its etale sheafification on the big site. Let $X$ be a scheme. If we know that $H_{Zar}^i(X,\mathcal{F}_{Zar})\simeq H_{et}^i(X,\mathcal{F}_{et})$ (sheaf cohomology is taken wrt the small site of $X$) for all $i$ and $X$, can we say anything about the Zariski sheaf cohomology of $\mathcal{F}_{et}$? ($H_{Zar}^i(X,\mathcal{F}_{et})$)

Comment: Are you talking about sheaves on the big Zariski/étale sites?

Comment: No the small ones.

Comment: Then how do you get an étale sheaf from a Zariski sheaf? It won't even be a presheaf.

Comment: You are right, the Zariski sheaf needs to be on the big Zariski site. Cohomologies are taken in the small site.

Comment: Another point which was originally in my mind. If we have a Zariski sheaf on the small site, we can define an etale sheaf simply by pullback. First construct a presheaf using the pullback then sheafify it.